# Opencv Recursive issue

Tags: c++, c, opencv, recursion, computer-vision

I'm still pretty new with working on OpenCV projects, but I've encountered an issue with a recursive function that I've been working on for a while now.

Basically the idea is too find connected components in an image using a strong and weak threshold. The code for this is below:

```
Mat DoubleThresholding(int thresh_strong, int thresh_weak, Mat image, int thresh_type, int denoise_k_size)
{
Mat strong, weak;
// cc_mask will be a global variable so it can be modified 
// by the Connector function
if (image.channels() >1){
    cvtColor( image, image, COLOR_RGB2GRAY ); // cvtColor(src, dst, code,dstCn)
}
threshold(image, weak, thresh_weak, 50, thresh_type);
threshold(image, strong, thresh_strong, 50, thresh_type);
 if(denoise_k_size>0){
Denoise(strong, denoise_k_size);
}

cc_mask = strong+weak;

for(int i=0; i<image.cols; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<image.rows; j++)
            {
                if(cc_mask.at<uchar>(j,i)==100)
                {
                    cc_mask.at<uchar>(j,i)=255;
                    //printf("mistake caught at row =%i col =%i )\n" , j,i);
                    if((i-1)>0) {Connector(i-1,j);}
                    if((i+1)<image.cols)    {Connector(i+1,j);}
                    if((j-1)>0) {Connector(i,j-1);}
                    if((j+1)<image.rows)    {Connector(i,j+1);}
                }
            }
    }


for(int i=0; i<image.cols; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<image.rows; j++)
            {
                if(cc_mask.at<uchar>(j,i)!=255)
                {

                    cc_mask.at<uchar>(j,i) = 0;             
                }
            }
    }



return cc_mask.clone();

};





void Connector( int i, int j)
{
if (cc_mask.empty() == true)
{

    return;
}
if (i<0 || i>cc_mask.cols || j<0 || j>cc_mask.rows)
{

    return;
}
else
{
    if(cc_mask.at<uchar>(j,i) == 50)
    {
    cc_mask.at<uchar>(j,i) = 255;
    Connector(i-1,j);
    Connector(i+1,j);
    Connector(i,j-1);
    Connector(i,j+1);

    }
    return ;
}


};
```

I keep getting a seg fault issue, and I know it has something to do with trying to access somthing that is out of bounds, but I can't for the life of me figure out what case(s) I seem to be missing.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You should run it under a debugger and see if you can identify where it's crashing, what the variable values are at that point, etc.  It might not be out-of-bound array access -- it could also be that your recursion is going too deep and exhausting the available stack space.

Comment: one off errors in Connector(): i>cc_mask.cols should be i>=cc_mask.cols ,j>cc_mask.rows should be j>=cc_mask.rows

Comment: after using a debugger, it appears that Jim's answer is correct, the function is just going to deep. I think i'll try to rewrite it as a while loop and see if it works any better. Thanks!!